# view.remove() on a sub view is called before it is instantiated in backbone, resulting in zombie views

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, memory-leaks, view, zombie-process

I have 8 main views and in each main view i am creating 2, 3 sub-view; also every main view has a method "deleteChildViews" for deleting its child views which is called before the main view is removed.

Now if user frequently switches from one main view to another then for each main view its "deleteChildViews" method is called.

PROBLEM

since each child sub-view has require in it for AMD, it takes some time to initialize and return its object. for this mean time the variable in which view is assigned will be undefined.

Every time we shift from one main view to another, deleteChildViews of the loaded view is called for child view cleanup and after which new view is initiated. Due to frequent shift from one main view to another, when the deleteChildViews method is called from parent(main view), its child views are found to be undefined so the function terminates without child cleanup. After some time those child view come into existence, resulting into zombie view leaving no any reference behind to remove those.

Which approach should i use to remove these zombie view? Sometimes they result in waking up of the dead main views as well.

Code in router, the function called before a particular view is initialize for a given route.

```
routes: {
    main: mainHandler
},
initialize: function () {
    $(window).off().on("hashchange", that.remove_previous_view);
},
mainHandler: function () {
    // initializing mianView
    that.view = new mainView();
},
remove_previous_view = function () {
    if (that.view) {
        // method called to delete sub-views
        that.view.deleteChildViews();
        //removing child view itself
        that.view.remove();
    }
}
```

Code in mainView

```
initialize: function () {
    this.render();
},
render: function () {
    this.el.html(_.template('mainTemplate'));
    this.initiateChildView();
},
initiateChildView: function () {
    this.childView = new ChildView();
},
deleteChildViews: function () {
    if (this.childView) {
        //used to remove childViews inside the child views.
        this.childView.deleteChildViews();
        this.childView.remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can post add some code here ?

Comment: @Manikandan I have added some sample code. Let me know if any clarification is required